# Question about a quine in a specific language

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

If I am interested in asking a question about quining in a specific language, would this be allowed?

I am curious as to whether or not its even possible to write such a quine in a certain language.

Comment: This would almost certainly be closed as a duplicate of our [general quine challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69/8478). The best option to challenge people to write a quine in a specific language is to put a bounty on that challenge. Of course, you don't have the reputation for that yet. Alternatively, [you can join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) where you'll often find people who would be interested to look into this. (May I ask which language you're thinking about?)

Comment: So I wrote an interpreter to a simple language as a proof of concept. I am interested out of curiosity whether its even possible to write a quine in.@MartinEnder

Comment: I see. Like I said, you might find people in the chat room I linked who would be interested in that. Alternatively [there's this room dedicated to programming languages](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27364/esoteric-programming-languages). It's a lot quieter, but a few users check it out regularly, so you'll likely get a response there as well. Alternatively, just answer some basic challenges like Hello World, cat and prime testing with it to get some attention, and maybe someone will have a look at it as well. :)

Comment: Thanks @MartinEnder